# Alternatives to sodium bicarbonate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I am searching for a molecule that is edible for human, reacts to liquid by generating $\ce{CO2}$ or a similar gas and that leaves behind a clear liquid, similar to sodium bicarbonate but without the milky whiteness.
Any ideas?

Comment: Sodium bitartrate?

Answer (score 1):

Ammonium bicarbonate, "baker's ammonia", is sometimes used as a leavening agent for baking (e.g. cookies) as it decomposes to gaseous ammonia, water, and carbon dioxide which are driven off in the oven heat. You can get it in some food stores. Hope this is helpful.